# How to solve zero Argument constructor error in PreferredSize flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, constructor, widget

I am working on a project where I am using a custom AppBar and hence using `PreferredSize` but I am getting a error stating that:

`The superclass 'PreferredSize' doesn't have a zero argument constructor. Try declaring a zero argument constructor in 'PreferredSize', or explicitly invoking a different constructor in 'PreferredSize'.`

Here's my part of the code:

```
class CustomAppBar extends PreferredSize {
  final Widget child;
  final double height;


  CustomAppBar({required this.child, required this.height}); //getting error on this line

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container()
}
}
```

Edit :
After removing PreferredSize got this error:

`The named parameter 'child' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'child'.`

```
appBar: 
PreferredSize(
preferredSize:Size.fromHeight(95),
child:
AppBar(
  
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(height: 40),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Builder(
            builder: (context) => FlatButton.icon(
                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                label: Text('')),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 60),
          Text('Times ',
              style: GoogleFonts.blackHanSans(
                  textStyle:
                      TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20))),
          Image.asset(
            'assets/newss.png',
            height: 50,
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: You forgot to pass the required parameters to the super constructor. The error itself is telling you that.

Comment: How to pass that?

Comment: calling the super constructor ": super()" at the end of your own object constructor. There's plenty of examples online. I'll recommend to learn more about Dart programming language and OOP as it's one of the most common patterns.

Comment: `The named parameter 'child' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.dart(missing_required_argument)
The named parameter 'preferredSize' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.`

Comment: getting this error now

Comment: follow what the error is telling you... child is required and preferredSize as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not even have to extend `PreferredSize` you may just wrap an appBar or any other widget inside a `PreferredSize` and just specify its height.

```dart
PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(72),
            child: AppBar(
              title: Text(title, style: TextStyles.h1),
              centerTitle: false,
              elevation: 0,
              brightness: Brightness.light,
              backwardsCompatibility: false,
              bottom: bottomAppBarWidget,
            ))
```

Comment: changed it but getting a different error,I updated the error in the question

Comment: Yes, but appBar does not have a child attribute, you should use `title` ,`actions`, `bottom` .`leading` etc to customize its content. The IDE autocomplete is your friend

Comment: Thanks for the help!