# Not getting the scaffold context in flutter custom app bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have written this flutter widget which I wanted to implement a custom app bar along with a drawer. Here is my starting widget

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Food App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
          body: HomeScreen(),
          drawer: CustomDrawer(),
          appBar: homeAppBar(context, (context) {
            Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
          }),
        ));
  }
}
```

I have implemented a callback in the app bar icon button

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:food_app/constants.dart';

AppBar homeAppBar(BuildContext context, Function function) {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0,
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/menu.svg"),
      onPressed: () {
        function(context);
      },
    ),
    title: RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .headline6
            .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: "Makana",
            style: TextStyle(color: ksecondaryColor),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: "Food",
            style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/notification.svg"),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

It gives me an error

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.

No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to Scaffold.of(). This usually happens when the context provided is from the same StatefulWidget as that whose build function actually creates the Scaffold widget being sought.

There are several ways to avoid this problem. The simplest is to use a Builder to get a context that is "under" the Scaffold. For an example of this, please see the documentation for Scaffold.of():
  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html
A more efficient solution is to split your build function into several widgets. This introduces a new context from which you can obtain the Scaffold. In this solution, you would have an outer widget that creates the Scaffold populated by instances of your new inner widgets, and then in these inner widgets you would use Scaffold.of().
A less elegant but more expedient solution is assign a GlobalKey to the Scaffold, then use the key.currentState property to obtain the ScaffoldState rather than using the Scaffold.of() function.

The context used was: MyApp
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
```

I have tried it like this also

```
AppBar homeAppBar(BuildContext context) {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0,
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/menu.svg"),
      onPressed: () {
        Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
      },
    ),
    title: RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .headline6
            .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: "Makana",
            style: TextStyle(color: ksecondaryColor),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: "Food",
            style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/notification.svg"),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Though it is under the scaffold from the main.dart, it still throws the same error. I tried Builder in app bar but it is not acceptable in AppBar return type.  I am a new bee into the flutter world. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the context that you are passing to the `homeAppBar` function does not have access to a Scaffold.

```dart
  @override
// The following context that is the one that you are passing to the function is above the scaffold and hence does not finds any scaffold "above" it.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Food App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
          body: HomeScreen(),
          drawer: CustomDrawer(),
          appBar: homeAppBar(context, (context) {
```

There are two solutions either wrap the `homeAppBar` inside a Builder like follows:

```dart
Builder(builder: (ctx)=>homeAppBar(ctx),)
```

Or just instead of using a function refactor the widget to use a class which is the one I would recommend for optimization reasons see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets) for a thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks, it helped!

Comment: Builder(builder: (ctx)=>homeAppBar(ctx),) it is not applicable to the PreferredSizedWidget.

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67706471/how-to-solve-zero-argument-constructor-error-in-preferredsize-flutter/67709448#67709448). The idea is to extract your appbar to another class and in `MyApp` call that new widget wrapped inside a PreferredSize.